# Why wont my Toyota dual cab 2004 3.0lt turbo diesel wont go over 100km/hour

Tags: toyota, air-intake, air-filter, hilux

I have just bought a new Hilux, its had work done too it aswell as been RWC approved and registered. But i notice yesterday coming back home that it was struggling to get up to 100 or over. I am thinking its blocked air filters but am not 100% sure? any Intel would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be anything at this point, it's hard to guess if you don't give more details.

Does it accelerate slowly, does it make any noises/vibrations, did you have other problems in the past? Does smoke come out of the exhaust, if yes when and what colour? Does it overheat when youb keep pushing it at 100km/h, did you notice poor fuel economy? Are any warning dashlights on? Does the car roll easily when depressing the clutch/selecting neutral, or does it come to a stop quickly?

It could be a leaking turbo then power will be low at all times, it may also be in limp-home mode, power will sometimes only be restricted by a lowered rpm limit.

If you do suspect the airfilter(i doubt so), take a look at it. Try to drive without it(that's fine for a few km's) and see if your problem disappears. If so, then it's solved and you only have to replace the airfilter.

Comment: Hey guys, i have only just bought the car, previous owner said it was serviced regulary, over all in good condition, had had 2 mechanic look at it and they didnt notice any issues and said its probably cause its an old dirty desiel.. 
it drives perfect, no noises or any lights on showing warnings, the ute just really struggles to get over 100.  it was also serviced and passed safety certificate last week in at the mechanics and had work done to it.

Comment: @kimberlys Any 3.0litre turbo diesel should be able to get a pick-up over 100kmh without the slightest effort, even if worn and old. Heck even my old 1.9litre non-turbo VW bus from 1996 could reach 160kmh. If you're sure it's a turbocharged engine, it's likely the turbo doesn't work anymore. If so, you'd better get rid of it as it now only increases fuel consumption, and reduces power. Better is it to get it replaced if budget allows so, obviously. Another possible cause is loss of compression. It's easy and cheap to get that tested, so it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, air filters are a relatively cheap and easy item to replace as a first step.

When was it last serviced? If you don't have that info then best advice would be to have that done straight away.

Could be many things - are the brakes hotter than normal - they may be dragging - will normally be noticed on a service - if the place is good...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any vapour or pressure from the Engine oil level stick ?

if so then you have leakage of combustion gas into the Engine oil compartmnet, this lowers compression and reduce engine power.